# Query fails with 'ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected'

Tags: sql, oracle, report

```
select pl.label_id,
( select pv.label_value 
from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pv 
where pv.locale_id='English' 
and pv.label_type_id = 'LABEL'
and pv.label_id = pl.label_id ) as 'English',
( select pv.label_value 
from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pv 
where pv.locale_id='Hindi' 
and pv.label_type_id = 'LABEL'
and pv.label_id = pl.label_id ) as 'Hindi',

from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pl
where pl.label_type_id = 'LABEL'
order by pl.label_id
```

The error is

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Comment: There is no point of posting multiple or long stack. You need to be very specific with your blocker

Comment: You have a comma before the `from`.  I vote to close as a simple typographic error.

Comment: Thanks, it was a silly mistake

Comment: Ravi- i need to make my column vale as my column heading, that's the reason i need to stack up

Comment: This is why we format code. As soon as you do that the error jumps out at you, without the need for 300+ lines of Java framework stack trace.

Comment: select
( select pv.label_value 
from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pv 
where pv.locale_id='English' 
and pv.label_type_id = 'LABEL'
and pv.label_id = pl.label_id ) as 'English',
( select pv.label_value 
from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pv 
where pv.locale_id='Hindi' 
and pv.label_type_id = 'LABEL'
and pv.label_id = pl.label_id ) as 'Hindi'
from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pl
where pl.label_type_id = 'LABEL'

Still error exist after removing the ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra `,` in your `SQL`, which is just before `FROM` keyword.

```
and pv.label_id = pl.label_id ) as 'Hindi',

from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pl
```

**==Edited==**

I'm not sure, why are you making query so complex, when it can be done easily. Why are you using inline query, when same thing you can achieve by using `CASE` statement.

```
select CASE WHEN pl.locale_id='English' THEN 
pl.label_value 
END  as 'English',
CASE WHEN pl.locale_id='Hindi' THEN 
pl.label_value 
END  as 'Hindi'  from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pl where pl.label_type_id = 'LABEL';
```

Comment: (select
( select pv.label_value 
from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pv 
where pv.locale_id='English' 
and pv.label_type_id = 'LABEL'
and pv.label_id = pl.label_id ) as 'English',
( select pv.label_value 
from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pv 
where pv.locale_id='Hindi' 
and pv.label_type_id = 'LABEL'
and pv.label_id = pl.label_id ) as 'Hindi'
from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pl
where pl.label_type_id = 'LABEL')

@Ravi, still error exist after changes in query

Comment: @ChinmoyNandi what error ??? don't simply copy paste the SQL query, you need to be very specific with what you are trying to ask

Comment: ;
    java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

The same one

Comment: @ChinmoyNandi check my updated post. You are a `Software Engineer`, at least you should know how to debug your issue instead asking for spoon feeding. This is one of the simplest query, I ever seen

Answer (score 1):

Remove "," before from keyword

Comment: (select ( select pv.label_value from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pv where pv.locale_id='English' and pv.label_type_id = 'LABEL' and pv.label_id = pl.label_id ) as 'English', ( select pv.label_value from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pv where pv.locale_id='Hindi' and pv.label_type_id = 'LABEL' and pv.label_id = pl.label_id ) as 'Hindi' from PV_I18N_ACTIVE_LOCALE_LABEL pl where pl.label_type_id = 'LABEL')
still error exist after changes in query

Comment: It should not. The same error pops up or another one?